# create sparse array from diagonal parts

Tags: python, scipy

How to construct sparse matrix from diagonal vectors like this:
Lets say my matrix is square with dimension N=6 and i have the following vector

```
vec =  np.array([[1], [1,2]])
```

and I want to put those parts on diagonals

```
offset = np.array([2,3])
```

but vec[0] should start at Mat[0,2] and vec[1] should start at Mat[1,4]

I know about scipy.sparse.diags() but I don't think there is a way to specify just part of a diagonal where non-zero elements are present.

This is just an example to illustrate the problem. In reality I deal with very big arrays and I dont want to waste memory for useless zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the matrix that you want?

```
In [200]: sparse.dia_matrix(([[0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,2]],[2,3]),(6,6)).A
Out[200]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Yes, the specification includes zeros, which could be annoying in larger cases.

`spdiags` just wraps the `dia_matrix`, with the option of converting the result to another format.  In your example that converts a 7 element sparse to a 3.

`sparse.diags` accepts a ragged list of values, but they still need to match the diagonals in length.  And internally it converts them to the rectangular array that `dia_matrix` takes.

```
S3=sparse.diags([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,2]],[2,3],(6,6))
```

So if you really need to be parsimonious about the zeros you need to go the `coo` route.

For example:

```
In [363]: starts = [[0,2],[1,4]]
In [364]: data = np.concatenate(vec)
In [365]: rows=np.concatenate([range(s[0],s[0]+len(v)) for s,v in zip(starts, vec)])
In [366]: cols=np.concatenate([range(s[1],s[1]+len(v)) for s,v in zip(starts, vec)])
In [367]: sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)),(6,6)).A
Out[367]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```